# DynamoDB putItem with condition but return complete item from table

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table with pk/sk composition as key and I want to save and item with the following conditions:

1. If the item (pk/sk) does not exist create it
2. If the item does exist and status is `DONE` update it but return the complete item (with all attributes) from the db
3. If the item does exist and status is not `DONE` throw error `status is not Done`.

I was hoping to use only one `PutItemCommand` something like this:

```
 const putItemCommand = new PutItemCommand({
    TableName: "MY_TABLE",
    Item: {
      pk: { S: item.pk },
      sk: { S: item.sk },
      status: { S: item.status },
      userID: { S: item.userID || "" },
      requestId: { S: item.requestId }
    },
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(pk) AND attribute_not_exists(sk) OR #status = :done',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#status": "status"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":done": { S: "DONE" }
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_OLD"
  });
```

But in the docs it says about `ReturnValues` in combination with `PutItemCommand`:

```
Use ReturnValues if you want to get the item attributes as
they appeared before they were updated with the PutItem request.
```

This means, (afaik)  when I update an item with this command I do not get any additional
attributes from this item back even if they are in the table, I only get those back I am
trying to update.

Is that correct?

If this is the case, I need an additional `GetItemCommand` when `result.Attributes` is not empty:

```
const result = await dynamoDBClient.send(putItemCommand);
    if(result.Attributes) {
      // this means an item got updated
      const newItem = await dynamoDBClient.send(/* new GetItemCommand() */)
    } else
    {
      // this means a new item has be created
    }
```

Will this `GetItemCommand` return the newly created item or does it need time to propagate?

I can `try..catch` the `PutItem` to throw an error, but how do I distinguish between a `normal` error and if the condition (meaning an item already exist with a status not equal to `DONE`) is not met?

Is this a valid approach to that issue, or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB PutItem does not return the values when a condition fails, but TransactWrireItems does. However, I believe for your use case it would be more efficient to read after write if you get an exception.

DynamoDB can do strongly consistent reads meaning you do not have to wait on propagation time, simply set `ConsistentRead: True`.

Furthermore, you do not need the if_exists condition, use `UpdateItem` which will create it if it does not exist by default.

Comment: thank you, is there a way in the PutItemCommand to update the item with a different status when it is an update then it is a create?
So if the item exists and the status is `Done` the status should be `InProgress` but if the item does not exist the status should be `Created`?

Comment: No, you can't achieve if/else conditional logic. Have your condition set to the one that will likely succeed and if it fails catch the exception and update the item accordingly.